# SQL Azure powershell commands not recognized anymore. Deprecated?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-rm

Already discussed at: [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer : The term 'Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45904816-84af-42a3-834d-6e31d2ca0bd2)

I just need to be sure if this behavior is due to the whole Azure Services Management deprecated ? Replaced by AzureRM or is it something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cmdlet doesn't start with `<verb>-AzureRm*` then it's not part of the `AzureRm` module.

`Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer` appears to be part of the `Azure` module, which is deprecated.

Perhaps you are looking for [`Get-AzureRmSqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqlserver?view=azurermps-6.10.0)?

`Get-Help Get-AzureRmSqlServer`

```
NAME
Get-AzureRmSqlServer

SYNOPSIS
Returns information about SQL Database servers.


SYNTAX
Get-AzureRmSqlServer [[-ResourceGroupName] <System.String>] [[-ServerName] 
<System.String>] [-DefaultProfile <Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authenticatio
n.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer>] [-Confirm 
<System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter>] [-WhatIf 
<System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
The Get-AzureRmSqlServer cmdlet returns information about one or more Azure SQL 
Database servers. Specify the name of a server to see information for only that 
server.
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I know it is not part of the AzureRM. AzureRM is a different, new stack perhaps, better and more powerful. What made me ask this question is due to having very limited knowledge and experience in powershell and scripts. 

Unfortunately my exam book (70-765) is full of the earlier mentioned (non AzureRm) cmdlets. Just wanted to be sure so that i myself can replace all the <verb>-AzureSqlDatabase syntaxt commands with the AzureRm :-)

Thanks gvee

Comment: As you can see in the example cmdlet your provided; you can't simply replace `Azure` with `AzureRm` in every case... but they're generally pretty close! You can always search for cmdlets in a module using `Get-Command -Module AzureRm*`